# MySQL 8 - Date comparison isn't working. Same query works in 5.6

Tags: mysql

I've been working on MySQL 5.6 Innodb for past few years. But i'm new to the features of MySQL 8.0. I use the below query in 5.6 & the results are as expected below,

```
SELECT date(m.dt) 
FROM (SELECT date_add(date("2021-08-20 00:00:00"), INTERVAL t.n DAY) dt 
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Tens.N * 10 + Ones.N AS n 
            FROM (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) Tens, 
                 (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10) Ones 
            ORDER BY n) t 
      WHERE t.n <= timestampdiff(DAY, "2021-08-20 00:00:00", "2021-09-26 23:59:59"))m 
WHERE date(m.dt) >= date('2021-09-24');

+------------+
| date(m.dt) |
+------------+
| 2021-09-24 |
| 2021-09-25 |
| 2021-09-26 |
+------------+

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Same query is NOT working in MySQL 8.0 & the results are weird,

```
SELECT date(m.dt) 
FROM (SELECT date_add(date("2021-08-20 00:00:00"), INTERVAL t.n DAY) dt 
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Tens.N * 10 + Ones.N AS n 
            FROM (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) Tens, 
                 (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10) Ones 
            ORDER BY n) t 
      WHERE t.n <= timestampdiff(DAY, "2021-08-20 00:00:00", "2021-09-26 23:59:59"))m 
WHERE date(m.dt) >= date('2021-09-24');

+------------+
| date(m.dt) |
+------------+
| 2021-08-30 |
| 2021-08-30 |
| 2021-08-30 |
+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

MySQL 8.0 has the below configurations,

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;

+------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.sql_mode      |
+------------------------+
| NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+------------------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%strict%';

+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| innodb_strict_mode | ON    |
+--------------------+-------+
```

Please advise me on where i'm going wrong.

Comment: *Same query is NOT working in MySQL 8.0 & the results are weird,* - ??? Everything works correctly in both mentioned versions. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mysql_5.6&fiddle=2cc2f39b9a8c465a579dcacbf0ddcce5

Comment: No. It's not working with 8.0.25 as evident below,

Comment: mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 32
Server version: 8.0.25 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Comment: mysql> SELECT date(m.dt)  FROM (SELECT date_add(date("2021-08-20 00:00:00"), INTERVAL t.n DAY) dt  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Tens.N * 10 + Ones.N AS n  FROM (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) Tens,  (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10) Ones  ORDER BY n) t  WHERE t.n
<= timestampdiff(DAY, "2021-08-20 00:00:00", "2021-09-26 23:59:59"))m  WHERE date(m.dt) >= date('2021-09-24');

Comment: +------------+
| date(m.dt) |
+------------+
| 2021-08-30 |
| 2021-08-30 |
| 2021-08-30 |
+------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

Comment: Just looking at the last line and the results are dead wrong... `date(m.dt) >= date('2021-09-24')` cannot produce `2021-08-30`.

Comment: But, i could reproduce the reported issue consistently with MySQL 8.0.25. Is there any configuration i must look into?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, I was able to confirm your behaviour for MySQL 8.0.25. It is fixed in MySQL 8.0.26.

It is probably somehow related to (or indirectly fixed by) [this bugfix](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-26.html):

> When outer batched key access and block-nested loop (or hash join) occurred together in a query, both were reverted to nested loops in the plan interpretation to access paths. Problems arose in some cases in which non-equality join conditions had been pushed to a special kind of BKA index condition, and by converting to a regular index lookup (which does not check the BKA condition), it was possible to drop conditions that should have been checked.

As a workaround, you can force materialisation of your subquery to prevent MySQL to outsmart itself, e.g. by adding a `limit`:

```
SELECT date(m.dt) 
FROM (SELECT date_add(date("2021-08-20 00:00:00"), INTERVAL t.n DAY) dt 
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Tens.N * 10 + Ones.N AS n 
            FROM (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) Tens, 
                 (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10) Ones 
            ORDER BY n LIMIT 100000) t -- add this limit
      WHERE t.n <= timestampdiff(DAY, "2021-08-20 00:00:00", "2021-09-26 23:59:59"))m 
WHERE date(m.dt) >= date('2021-09-24');
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info & the work around, friend!